# Heat storage mass vs. AIR in an ICF house

Tags: civil-engineering, building-design, building-physics, architecture, home-improvement

If we would want to build a family house (ICF) regarding operational costs, should we leave the insulation on the inside, or should we remove it from the inside?

If we would remove it, the walls would provide a great thermal mass.

But if we would leave it as it, as a normal ICF, then we would only need to heat/cool the AIR inside and not the walls.

**Q:** which solution would have less operational cost?

House is a very energy efficient one, almost passive house. Big windows facing south (in summer, outside shaders against the sun)

Comment: Third option, put the insulation on the outside then that increases thermal mass storage inside...

Comment: ICF has insulation at the outside (thicker) and insulation in the inside too. We are not sure to remove it from the inside or not.